# How to make attribute_names list all attribute names in a document with dynamic attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, dynamic-attributes

I have a Rails 4.2 application with mongoid in which I'm importing csv files with test results. I can't define all fields in the model because they change from test to test and theres always around 700 of them. I use Dynamic Attributes and importing and displaying works fine.

I'm trying to use attribute_names method to get all attribute names but all I get is those defined in the model. If I don't define anything in the model it comes back with "_id" only. attributes method on the other hand can see attributes in the actual document on the other hand.

```
>> @results.first.attributes.count
=> 763
>> @results.first.attribute_names
=> ["_id"]
```

I also tried fields.keys, same problem

```
>> @results.first.fields.keys
=> ["_id"]
```

My model at the moment looks like this

```
class Result
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
        Result.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
end
```

Can somebody explain how to make it work?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This part is not very clear in the documentation.
and this answer doesn't address how you can make your case works ( I really don't know)... **but it has one monkey patch at the end...**

all I know is why this case **not** working...

as the [documentation states](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#dynamic_fields)

> When dealing with dynamic attributes the following rules apply:
>
> If the attribute exists in the document, Mongoid will provide you with your standard getter and setter methods.
>
> For example, consider a person who has an attribute of "gender" set on the document:
>
> ```
> # Set the person's gender to male.
> person[:gender] = "Male"
> person.gender = "Male"
>
> # Get the person's gender.
> person.gender
> ```

this is not your case... cause as it appears you are not defining any attributes in your model...

**what applies in your case (from the code you showed and problem you described)**

> If the attribute does not already exist on the document,
>
> **Mongoid will not provide you with the getters and setters** and will enforce normal `method_missing` behavior.
>
> In this case you must use the other provided accessor methods: (`[]` and `[]=`) or (`read_attribute` and `write_attribute`).
>
> ```
> # Raise a NoMethodError if value isn't set.
> person.gender
> person.gender = "Male"
>
> # Retrieve a dynamic field safely.
> person[:gender]
> person.read_attribute(:gender)
>
> # Write a dynamic field safely.
> person[:gender] = "Male"
> person.write_attribute(:gender, "Male")
> ```

as you can see... there is no way for mongoid to add the setter and getter methods in runtime...

#### Monkey Patch

- you could add a field (maybe string, array, hash, whatever suites you) to the document (attribute exists in the document)
- on populating the document from the CSV row.. just save what are the fields of the CSV in that field... (hold the CSV keys in it)
- use your predefined field (that holds the keys) instead of using `.keys`.

code example in your case.

```
class Result
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

  field :the_field_that_holds_the_keys, type: Array
  # ...
end
```

and in your controller:

```
@results.first.some_attribute
#=> method missing error
@results.first[:some_attribute]
#=> some_value
@results.first.the_field_that_holds_the_keys
#=> [:some_attribute, :some_other_attribute, :yada]
```